# The DateTimeIndex is gone after a merge. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with over 1000 records. The index is on the booking date

```
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    DatetimeIndex: 1642 entries, 2021-01-03 to 2021-12-16
    Data columns (total 26 columns):
     #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
    ---  ------                     --------------  -----         
     0   bankrek                    1642 non-null   object        
     1   Munt                       1642 non-null   object        
     ......
     ......       
     23  Oorspr munt                0 non-null      float64       
     24  Koers                      0 non-null      float64       
     25  category                   1642 non-null   object        
    dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(9), int64(1), object(15)
    memory usage: 346.4+ KB
```

After I do a .merge my date timeIndex is gone. The merge does a vlookup on the category table and ads two text columns

```
dfIn=dfIn.merge(dfGrootboek, how="left", on="category")
dfIn.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1642 entries, 0 to 1641
Data columns (total 28 columns):
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                     --------------  -----         
 0   bankrek                    1642 non-null   object        
 1   Munt                       1642 non-null   object        
 2   BIC                        1642 non-null   object        
 3   Volgnr                     1642 non-null   int64         
 ....
  
 ....      
 23  Oorspr munt                0 non-null      float64       
 24  Koers                      0 non-null      float64       
 25  category                   1642 non-null   object        
 26  Grootboek                  1578 non-null   object        
 27  Kleinboek                  1578 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(9), int64(1), object(17)
memory usage: 372.0+ KB
```

The output is as wanted except for the fact that my datum index is gone, instead I see numbers. I want to keep the date index because I need it for reporting per month and so on.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: merges destroy the index when the index isn't use as a merge key. Since a DataFrame can only have one Index, _which_ index should pandas choose when rows match, the one from the left frame or the one from the right? If you need to bring that information along, `.reset_index` before the merge so it's brought along as a column, then you can `.set_index` after the merge

Comment: Thanks Alollz that did the job.